# Why don't unit circle poles lead to infinite amplitude response for Butterworth lowpass?

Tags: filters, frequency-response, digital-filters, poles-zeros, butterworth

This is probably a very stupid question. In many places (e.g. [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/understanding-butterworth-filter-pole-locations/)), the Butterworth filters, e.g. lowpass, are described as being "allpole" filters, that have all of these poles [on the unit circle](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/filter-shape-from-poles-and-zeros.820041/post-5147793).

But shouldn't poles on the unit circle lead to a pole in the amplitude response of the filter at that particular frequency, in the same way as a zero attenuates that particular frequency? Instead, the Butterworth lowpass has strong attenuation in the upper frequency spectrum, despite having all of its poles on the left-hand side of the unit circle (the high frequency side).

Could anyone please clear my confusion ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've made an understandable mistake.  You are probably looking at this picture:

[image: Picture of Butterworth poles, in a circle on the s plane]

That is *not* the unit circle, and it isn't even in the $z$ domain.

What you are looking at is the locations of the poles for a 4-pole Butterworth filter *in the Laplace domain*.  These are values of $s$, not $z$, and the circle is not a unit circle -- it's radius is defined by the cutoff frequency of the filter (which is why the radius is indicated as being $\omega_0$).

The Butterworth is one of the "old modern" filters, invented before we could just start with a desired frequency-domain response and synthesize the optimal filter.  All of these (Butterworth, Tchebychev, eliptic, Gaussian) were originally designed as *continuous-time* filters, and the canonical representations of them are in the Laplace ($s$) domain.  Implementations of these as IIR filters in the $z$ domain are sometimes-useful approximations.

Comment: Aha thanks. I am sure I have also seen a reference, that said explicitly that the Butterworth poles are on the "unit circle" though - which seems false now. Are the pole and zero positions in this "s" domain also intuitively useful for something, such as those in the "z" domain that give a reasonable feeling for the amplitude frequency response, as one "walks along the unit circle" ?

Comment: The unit circle in the z-plane maps to the imaginary axis of the s-plane.

Comment: "... that said explicitly that the Butterworth poles are on the "unit circle" though".  You can _edit your question_ with that comment.  Especially if you can cite the reference.  It's pretty common to design filters in the $s$ domain that are normalized to $\omega_0 = 1$ (no units).  In that case, the Butterworth poles _would_ be on _that_ unit circle -- but it's not the _z Transform's_ unit circle.

Comment: I added the second link. Thanks anyway to you and @Hilmar . It looks like the s domain is a whole different world to the z domain and all of the little I knew about the z domain doesnt apply to s domain. So I need to read and learn a lot about the uses of the s domain, which so far I have had no reason for.

Comment: @tobalt Perhaps the material at the following web page would be helpful to you, https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/994.php

Comment: @RichardLyons thanks for this link. It is helpful. Btw, I interpret Tim's comment at dsprelated as being aimed at the dark purple line. The infinitesimal region around s=0 is similar to the infinitesimal region around z=1. Therefore, the dark purple line should "launch" towards "south-west" and not to "south south west". Also am I right to assume, that the right-half s-Plane corresponds to locations outside the z-domain unit circle, and that the mapping is a simple unambiguous transformation in both directions ?

Comment: "It looks like the s domain is a whole different world to the z domain"...  Well, yes and no.  Both are about turning "difficult" time-domain descriptions of linear time- (or shift-) invariant systems into much easier to handle frequency-domain descriptions.  Both involve reducing those descriptions to ratios of polynomials, both have regions of stability (or instability) -- much of the underlying math applies.  It's just the next layer up that doesn't -- it's like the difference between building a good solid house out of wood, vs. one out of stone or straw bales or whatever.

Comment: @TimWescott "the "old modern" filters" Is there a collective name I can google for the class of "new modern" synthesizable filters?

Comment: I don't know!  "Canonical continuous-time filters" maybe.  Or just "canonical filters".

Comment: "Is there a collective name I can google for the class of "new modern" synthesizable filters?" -- sorry, I missed that until now.  No, because these days we have much faster computers, so if one of the old standbys isn't good enough you synthesize a filter from the specifications.  Essentially, you custom-make one by tweaking the coefficients, except it's the computer that's doing the tweaking.